# How to look for the solution of Cauchy problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The Cauchy problem

$u_x(x,y) + u_y(x,y)=0$

$u(x,x)=0$

has

a) Unique solution

b) Family of straight lines as characterstics

c) Solution which vanishes at $(2,1)$

d) Infinitely many solutions

I solve it and i got the solution $u(x,y)=cf(x-y)$ where $f(0)=0$

c) holds because taking $0$ solution.

Now from this can i say a) false and what about b)?

Comment: d holds clearly bacause constant is present there

Comment: Do you know what characteristics are?